# Examples of parametric equations which is impossible to eliminate the parameter from?

Tags: calculus, parametric, parametrization

In the book "Calculus" by Stewart and others,
it is written as follows:

"It is not always possible to eliminate the parameter from parametric equations. There are many parametric curves that don’t have an equivalent
representation as an equation in $x$ and $y$."

But I cannot find such an example.
So, I want to know some examples.

Comment: To make the question rigorous, you'd have to specify which functions you are allowed to use to build the equation.